# In TypeScript, how to convert all types within a Union to an array of that type

Tags: typescript, union-types

Let's say I have the following:

```js
type UnionType = CustomType1 | CustomType2 | CustomType3;

// is there a way to accomplish this, without having to type it out like so.
type UnionTypeArr = CustomType1[] | CustomType2[] | CustomType3[];
```

Comment: Thank you for asking this question learn something really awesome from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) (a conditional type of the form `T extends X ? Y : Z` where `T` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter) to split a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)  into its members, perform a transformation on each member, and combine the result into another union:

```
type DistribArrayify<T> = T extends unknown ? Array<T> : never;

type UnionType = CustomType1 | CustomType2 | CustomType3;

type UnionTypeArr = DistribArrayify<UnionType>;
// type UnionTypeArr = CustomType1[] | CustomType2[] | CustomType3[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAFQE8AHCARmQG8AoZZOALmWylAHMaBfG0SWRCgzZ8xMgCZqdZACNmrDt17ho8JGiy5CpCAGYp9BPLBsQnHjRpgdyACLAFMgIJQocIsBhEAPAQB8yAC8yATIEAAekCAAJpjI6CAA1iA4AO4gyAD8yC5uPv7IzCAQAG7QANyW1mTIAKogwDggYijBwlotlAA+GiLaEsg97aI6upVWNvWNzTq5QXYOJsDOru6ePlNNLX6VAPS7yNUomzNkc22aI2TkANoAuoO9HTri94-D-Xr3QA)

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!